# Continuous version of Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: calculus, inequality

Proving the discrete version of Cauchy-Schwarz is easy:

$$ \left(\sum_{i} a_i^2\right)  \left(\sum_i b_i^2\right) \geq
    \left(\sum_i a_ib_i\right)^2 $$

can be done via the determinant of the quadratic formula.

Now, however, I want to prove the continuous version, which states:

$$ \int a^2 \int b^2 \geq \left(\int ab\right)^2$$

How do I prove this?

Comment: Well, aren't integrals defined in terms of sums?

Comment: Try to use the fact that $\int (a-cb)^2  \geq 0$ for all real numbers $c$ and then choose a clever value for $c$.

Comment: It's Cauchy--[Schwarz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Amandus_Schwarz) not [Schwartz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_Schwartz).  I fixed it for you.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Good catch, Thanks!

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I see, clever.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff : yes, taht's what I ended up doing.

Comment: @user1311390 Yes, clever.  Try it with $$c = \frac{\int ab}{\int b^2}$$ (assuming that $\int b^2 > 0$), and work out a separate proof for the case when $\int b^2 = 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that $ab \leq \frac{a^2}{2} + \frac{b^2}{2}$.  Then take $a = \frac{f}{(\int{f^2})^{\frac{1}{2}}}, b = \frac{g}{(\int{g^2})^{\frac{1}{2}}}$.

Comment: I like this solution. It's much better than what I ended up with (expressing the integrals as reinmen sums, and arguing that the approximations are within epsilon)